# Negative numbers in awk

Tags: awk

I have two negative numbers I am trying extract a range of numbers from a field using `awk`.  It works great with positive numbers... but when I try to do negative numbers I get the error.
`FILENAME=- FNR=1303`) `fatal attempt to access field -532` (where `-532` is one of my numbers)
Here is my line of code:

```
awk -v var=$per90u -v var2=$per90l -v var3-$field -F, '{ if ( $var3 >= var && $var3 <= var2 ) print $10 } < inputfile > outputfile
```

Any idea on correction?

Comment: post a testable sample

Comment: per90u=-543 per90l=-520  inputfile= -553 -547 -533 -528 -540 change print $10 to print $0 from my code example

Comment: @user378839, you can [edit] your post to add the commands and files you used. You can't really format them properly in comments...

Answer (score 1):

`$var3` is evaluated to the value of the field whose number is stored in `var3`, but AWK doesn’t have negative field numbers. Thus if `var3` is negative, you’ll get the error mentioned in your question.

If you’re expecting to use the value of `$field` directly, use `var3` instead of `$var3`. If that’s not the problem, you’ll need to revisit what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I just changed the $var3 to var3 and the error changed to FNR=2.  I think what I am going to do is change the values in inputfile to positive numbers and adjust the if statement accordingly.

Comment: @user378839 That could be done with a simple if statement in `awk` : `if ( var3 < 0 ) { var3=-var3 }`